# "Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame" error when running dbt seed

Tags: dbt

dbt version: 0.20.1
database: postgresql
code: https://github.com/josephmachado/simple_dbt_project

when running the command "dbt seed", it raises error:

```
Unhandled error while executing seed.tutorial.customer
Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('column')
19:17:41 | 1 of 3 ERROR loading seed file tutorial.customer..................... [ERROR in 3.61s]
19:17:41 | 3 of 3 START seed file tutorial.state................................ [RUN]
Unhandled error while executing seed.tutorial.state
Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('column')
19:17:41 | 3 of 3 ERROR loading seed file tutorial.state........................ [ERROR in 0.23s]
Unhandled error while executing seed.tutorial.orders
Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('column')
19:17:51 | 2 of 3 ERROR loading seed file tutorial.orders....................... [ERROR in 14.37s]
19:17:51 |
19:17:51 | Finished running 3 seeds in 14.96s.

Completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings:

Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('column')

Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('column')

Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to 

the frame ('column')
```

Any setting i am missing?

Comment: seems it doesn't work on windows environment.  it works on linux

Answer (score 3):

how did you install Jinja2? It should be the older version `2.x` Normally as you install dbt package, jinja comes with the right(older) version as dependency.
Check your jinja version per command:

```
pip freeze > temp.txt
```

if it is not `2.x`, You gotta take care of that.

Comment: it also might be an old version of the `agate` library. Def want to see OPs env

Answer (score 3):

Jinja2==3.0.1 caused this issue. It is fixed after installing Jinja2==2.11.3